# laravel database not being updated

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, insert-update

I have a model with two primary keys and I have already overrided the setKeysForSaveQuery(). $object->save() returned true and I tried to dd the updated data, it shows already being updated, but after refresh the database, it is not being updated.

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = ['number','type'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = [
       'number','type'
    ];

    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
    {
        $query
            ->where('number', '=', $this->getAttribute('number'))
            ->where('type', '=', $this->getAttribute('type'));
        return $query;
    }
}
```

This is how I update the model in my controller

```
$object=Test::where('number',$number)->where('type','string')->first();
$object->number=$target_number;
$object->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the key used to find the record so it will now use this new key in the query which isn't the current key in the database. You need to use the original keys so it can find the record, then it can update the record with new values.

You would need to do something like this:

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    $number = $this->original['number'] ?? $this->getAttribute('number');
    $type = $this->original['type'] ?? $this->getAttribute('type');

    $query->where('number', '=', $number)
        ->where('type', '=', $type);

    return $query;
}
```

This uses the original values for those keys if they exist and if not uses the current attribute value.